# Enterprise Architect 9 report template element>method not working properly

Tags: templates, report, enterprise-architect

I'm working with **Enterprise Architect 9** and I need to prepare a report of the Class Model.
I prepared a simple template and in the *Method* section with the *Parameter* subsection I have:

[image: Template]

But when I generate the document I have something like this:

[image: Generated RTF]

As you can see, the first row of the template only shows on the first method. However if I remove the *Parameter* subsection, it works properly.

Does anyone knows how to make it work? (of course, remove the parameters is not an option, I need that information too)

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Note**: In the second image, the yellow background of the word is because it's a search result in Word, ignore that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `Header Row` checked on the table.
This feature makes EA think there is a header row that doesn't need repeating because it contains the headers.
Select your top row, right click and select `Table|Header Row`

[image]